# Local mp3 stream Server

Tags: debian, streaming

I want to stream mp3 from my Debian based Nas to my Pioneer AV Receiver in my local Network.

I have a Receiver that support internet Radio streams and search for a simple way to stream mp3 and flac files to this Receiver.

I have no knowlege about streaming servers and search for the right one.

This server should be:

1. simple to use
2. should stream shuffled mp3 and flac files
3. should start stream on connection and stop stream on disconnect
4. and should reachable via local network from my Receiver like a internet radio stream (pls or something)

Do you know some streaming server how can manage that?

I have try IceCast2 but I had to setup some passwords and my Recaiver is not able to login.

Answer (score 1):

You can use icecast2 for this purpose without specify to use authentication.

From the [documentation](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.4.1/config-file.html#mountsettings):

**username**

```
An optional value which will set the username that a source must use to connect using this mountpoint. Do not set this value unless you are sure that the source clients connecting to the mount point can be configured to send a username other than source.
If this value is not present the default username is source.
```

**password**

```
An optional value which will set the password that a source must use to connect using this mountpoint. There is also a URL based authentication method for sources that can be used instead.
```